# Laptop fails to boot when plugged in but not on battery

Tags: boot, laptop, battery

My laptop is getting older (4-5 years old now) and I am having frequent issues with it failing to boot (freezing on BIOS screen, on Windows loading screen, on login screen, or some point in between). However, this seems only to happen when the laptop is plugged in, and not when it is on battery. I have had issues in the past (and ongoing, infrequently) where plugging in the power cable will not supply power to the laptop, either when it is on or off. These 'boot failures' occur even when I am certain the computer is getting power from the wall.

Is there a 'good' reason why this phenomenon is occurring?

Comment: Are you using an OEM power supply or a 3rd party replacement?

Comment: @Tyson it is the OEM power supply

Comment: Does this happen when you are plugged into a wall socket somewhere else (different house or across town)? Try a new power supply, if that does not cure it, there are more serious problems and you consider looking for a new laptop.